# What is this symbol for in vehicles?

Tags: battlefield-4

I have noticed this rhombus / Square shape with a dot in the middle in the bottom right corner to the left of my health while flying the jet.   What is this for?

[image]

Comment: I was thinking either ECM / flares, but there is a countdown on the jets hud (in the middle of the screen), so why would it be here? I can't be laser designation as I don't have it equipped...Still unsure about this.

Comment: Pretty sure it is missles of some sort, that is usually where the gernade symbol is when on foot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is countermeasures (Flares, ECM) counter. There is also indicator on vehicle screen (it changes between 'ready' and reload timer).